# Accessing json response inside javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Im new to json.I have a json string such like this

```
 {"myVar1":{"myVar2":["myVar3"]}}
```

I stored the json value in a variable called data.Now when i tried to access the myVar3 value like this i was not able to access it.I tried something like this

```
var dataVal = data.myVar1.myVar[0];
```

can anyone tell me where i've gone wrong and tell me how to access the value here?

Comment: Try `data.myVar1.myVar2[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like a tree..

```
var dataVal = data.myVar1.myVar2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`myVar2` is an array. you should access it.

```
var dataVal = data.myVar1.myVar2[0]
```

The structure looks like this:

```
myVar1 = {
  myVar2: [
    "myVar3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var dataVal = data.myVar1.myVar2[0];
```